# Is it possible to register a CXF Interceptor in more than one Phases?

Tags: java, rest, cxf, interceptor

I have a **CXF Rest Service** and I am trying to create a logging mechanism that will log specific `request` and `response` details.

All the details I want to be written into a file in one write. As a result I am looking forward to create an `Interceptor` that will be invoked in the `RECEIVE` and in the `SEND` phase. Until now I haven't find any way to do it.

Is it possible to create an Interceptor registered in **two** phases of **two** different chains?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just got an answer from the cxf-user mailing lists which is

> It’s not possible to register the exact same interceptor object in two
>   phases.  You can register two separate interceptors of the same class
>   on different phases, but not the same exact object.   The phase needs
>   to be set at construction time.
>
> Daniel Kulp

So the answer is No.

[link to post](http://cxf.547215.n5.nabble.com/Is-it-possible-to-register-an-interceptor-in-two-phases-td5738337.html)